# Memory allocation **p

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory

For the statement `int ** p = NULL;` in C, please discuss about the memory allocation of `p`, `*p`, `**p`? Whether it will be on stack or at null location or somewhere else???

Comment: But the answers shouldn't be discussions. Would you like to ask something specific instead ?

Comment: @peacemaker  no it is just anormal question i found during my course pointers in c in my school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` will be an `int **` pointer on the stack and will contain the value `NULL`.

Trying to evaluate `*p` will cause a runtime error as you will attempt to dereference `NULL`. But if it does not cause a runtime error it will be the value at memory location `0`.

Trying to evaluate `**p` is impossible to get to as `*p` is impossible to evaluate (will cause a runtime error). But if `*p` did not cause a runtime error then `**p` will be the value at the memory location pointed to by the value at memory location `0`.

EDIT: `*p` and `**p` are not allocated anywhere because they don't exist as separate variables. There is only one variable in memory, `p`, and that is stored on the stack. It's like asking, if I do `int i = 10;`, where is `i * 5` stored?

Comment: where *p and **p will get allocated??

Comment: If `p` is defined in a function without the keyword `static`, then it will probably be on the stack; if `p` is defined outside a function (or with the keyword `static` but inside a function), it will not be on the stack.  The address of `p` itself will not be 'at null location'.

Comment: @user1623827 `*p` and `**p` will never be allocated if you don't make the program to do so. The allocation is not implicit.

Answer (score 1):

- `p` is just a variable that points somewhere.
- Its type is `int**` which means it can point to a pointer to an `int`.
- Since you have not written any code that allocates memory, no memory allocation takes place..
- .. except ofcourse the memory allocation for `p` itself: assuming a 32 bit address space, 4 bytes of memory is allocated on the stack and the value at that memory address is a 0 (NULL).